# How to properly configure jquery .done method

Tags: jquery

I have a function that populates a listbox via AJAX.

```
function listCourses() {    
var s= document.getElementById( 'courses' );

return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:80/RickVideos/courseLib.xml",
    dataType: "xml",

    success: function( xml ){

        // load array with course codes
        var arr = [];
        $(xml).find( 'courseCode' ).each(function() {
                s.options[ s.options.length ] = new Option( $( this ).text());
        });

     },

    error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file." );
    }

});
```

When the function is invoked I'd like a modal dialog to display while the AJAX processing occurs and then have the modal dialog replaced with another modal dialog displaying the populated listbox.

```
 $(  "#ajaxLoading #listOfCurrentProjects" ).overlay({
    left: "center",
    top: "center", 
   closeOnClick: false, 
    load: false
}); 
$( "#newCourse" ).click( function() { 
   $("#ajaxLoading").overlay().load();

    listCourses().done(function() {
        $("#ajaxLoading").overlay().close();
        $("#listOfCurrentProjects").overlay().load();   
});;
```

When the `newCourse` button is clicked, the `ajaxLoading` dialog is displayed and then closes. The `listOfCurrentProjects` dialog does not display. When the `newCourse` button is clicked a second time the `ajaxLoading` dialog displays and is then closes being replaced by the `listOfCurrentProjects` dialog. This is the desired behavior. Why does it not happen on the initial button click?

Answer (score 0):

Use promises that are implemented in jQuery 1.5 onwards, such as `.done()`, instead. You can resolve not to use the `success` or `error` callback.

```
var listCourses = function() { 
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:80/RickVideos/courseLib.xml",
        dataType: "xml"
    });
});
```

You can call your AJAX whenever you want to, using `listCourses()`. You can even bind it to handler, almost like what you have done:

```
$('#newCourse').click(function() { 
    $('#ajaxLoading').overlay().load();

    listCourses().done(function(xml) {
        var s = document.getElementById('courses');
        $(xml).find( 'courseCode' ).each(function() {
            s.options[s.options.length] = new Option($( this ).text());
        });

        $("#ajaxLoading").overlay().close();
        $("#listOfCurrentProjects").overlay().load();
    }).error(function() {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file." );
    });
});
```

---

You can make it even more verbose, by making an AJAX call through a variable:

```
var listCourses = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:80/RickVideos/courseLib.xml",
    dataType: "xml"
});
```

And then simply refer to the variable `listCourses`, instead of the function `listCourse(s)`, when listening to the click eent on `#newCourse`:

```
$('#newCourse').click(function() { 
    $('#ajaxLoading').overlay().load();

    listCourses.done(function(xml) {
        var s = document.getElementById('courses');
        $(xml).find( 'courseCode' ).each(function() {
            s.options[s.options.length] = new Option($( this ).text());
        });

        $("#ajaxLoading").overlay().close();
        $("#listOfCurrentProjects").overlay().load();
    }).error(function() {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file." );
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried using the variable and the revised click event for #newCourse as suggested. The behavior is the same as I originally described: it requires two clicks of the #newCourse button to have the #listOfCurrentProjects displayed.